# Using regex to get everything in parentheses followed from particular word

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
text='2-05-13 15:31:48.253 StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote[5353:207339] Websocket: symbols: ({change = "0.5250015";changePercent = "1.49701"; dayVolume = 16608364; exchange = NYQ; id = BAC; marketHours = 1; price = "35.595"; priceHint = 4;quoteType = 8; time = 3304904610000})2022-05-13 15:31:48.256 StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote[5353:207339] Websocket: Streamer Prices Updat2022-05-13 15:31:48.256 StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote[5353:207343] refreshG2022-05-13 15:31:48.267 StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote[5353:207339] webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message: CgReREpJFRSv+0YY8MCp3ZdgKgNESkkwCTgBRb2+wz9ItLvjWGWAnvJD2A2022-05-13 15:31:48.267 StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote[5353:207339] Websocket: symbols: (  {  change = "485.2383";  changePercent = "1.529258";  dayVolume = 186178996;  exchange = DJI;  id = "^DJI";  marketHours = 1; price = "32215.54";  priceHint = 4; quoteType = 9; time = 3304904614000})'
```

and I want to extract only the following text:

```
symbols: (  {  change = "485.2383";  changePercent = "1.529258";  dayVolume = 186178996;  exchange = DJI;  id = "^DJI";  marketHours = 1; price = "32215.54";  priceHint = 4; quoteType = 9; time = 3304904614000})
```

and all the text in that specific format as this appears mutiple times in my dataset.

Therefore, I need a regex pattern that can extract all the data within the parentheses, including the parentheses and the word `symbols`. So something that searches for all the words `symbols` and finishes at the last closing parentheses and grabs al of these.

I have used  regex101 to build a pattern, and the closest I got to was this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/9gvEXC/1)
by using the following:

```
^[^\()]+(^.)\s
```

The structure of my text is like in the regex101 however, when it's just as a single string as given above, I used:

```
\(.*?\)
```

however it still grabs unncessary  text.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my post

Comment: Maybe like this `\bsymbols:\s*\({change\s*=[^{}]*}\)` https://regex101.com/r/ZzQca7/1

Comment: The string contains `'...symbols: ({change = "0.5250015";...symbols: (  {  change = "485.2383";...})`, where each `...` represents strings of characters other than `')'` and `'}'`. What is the rule that tells us that the string of interest begins, `'symbols: (  {  change = "485.2383";'`, rather than `'symbols: ({change = "0.5250015;"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the pattern a bit more specific:

```
\bsymbols:\s*\({change\s*=[^{}]*}\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bsymbols:\s*` Match the word `symbols`, then `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `\({` Match `({`
- `change\s*=` Match `change`, optional whitepace chars and `=`
- `[^{}]*` Match optional chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}\)` Match `})`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlNMXH/1)

Or only specifying symbols making the pattern a bit less strict:

```
\bsymbols:\s*\({[^{}]*}\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uP8nui/1)

Comment: This works great! I have noticed it does not capture the second one because it has white spaces between the curly brace and parentheses. Is there a way to generalise for white-spaces but also for new lines, so if it has or does not have them it grabs it?

Comment: @Workingdollar Then the pattern can be like this `\bsymbols:\s*\(\s*{[^{}]*}\s*\)` https://regex101.com/r/OGZdd1/1 There was only the first match in the question so I did not match the second one.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! thank you for showing me how it is done :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this regex:

```
symbols: *\( *{[^}]+} *\)
```

Explanation:

- `symbols:`: "symbols" word followed by colon
- `*`: any number of spaces
- `\(`: open parenthesis
- `*`: any number of spaces
- `{`: open curly brace
- `[^}]+`: any character other than curly brace
- `}`: closed curly brace
- `*`: any number of spaces
- `)`: closed parenthesis

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/TSDBjx/1).